# Python: 3 - make string after found keywords a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, input, substring

I'm trying to find an elegant (easy) way of saving a sub-string in a string as a variable if i don't know what the word will be, but i do know what the four words before it are.

If the string is ("reset the password for johnny.mnemonic"), i need to be able to store the string johnny.mnemonic after i've found the substring? But how?

```
string = " will you reset password for johnny.mnemonic please"
substring = "reset password for"


if string.find(substring) is not -1:
    print("i found the substring to request password reset")
    #now add the next sub-string to as a variable here, user should be be next string over
else:
    print("sorry, no request found.")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... Please provide examples...

Comment: added example code, hopefully that will better explain what i'm trying to do. i need to find the following string(or two) in a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is suitable solution for your situation:

```
cstring = " will you reset password for johnny.mnemonic please"
substring = "reset password for"

if substring in cstring:
    words = cstring.split()
    person = words[words.index('for')+1]
else:
    person = False

if person:
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_string = " will you reset password for johnny.mnemonic please"
substring = "reset password for " # keep in mind the ending space
first_index = input_string.find(substring)
if first_index != -1: # if found
    last_index = first_index + len(substring)
    print(input_string[last_index:].split(" ")[0]) # split into words and get the first word
```

Output:

```
johnny.mnemonic
```

Basically it will search for "reset password for " and then obtain the next word after the substring

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to store information concerning a certain person and retrieve this information using the person's name.
I would suggest to use a dictionary like so:

```
s = 'reset the password for johnny.mnemonic'
t = 'create the password for another.guy'
u = 'tell the password for a.gal'

d = {}
d[s.split()[-1]] = s
d[t.split()[-1]] = t
d[u.split()[-1]] = u


for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, '\n\t', v)
```